# Creating PDF from UIScrollView in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview

I am creating pdf from UIView to pdf it works fine but i have `scrollView` with content which i want to convert to pdf but it only show visible part in pdf not the whole `scrollView` content. here is my code

```
-(void)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
 {    
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    // Get Scrollview size
    CGRect scrollSize = CGRectMake(1018,76,scrollView.contentSize.width,scrollView.contentSize.height);

    // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, scrollSize, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData

    [aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];





    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
    NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

    NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

    // instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
    [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);
}
```

Comment: Visit this answer, it will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/6566696/1223897

Comment: @Yuvrajsinh this is the same code which i am using but it is for plain not for UIScrollView

Comment: I think the problem is, you are creating new UIView with static size.
Use yourScrollView.contentSize for getting exact content size (width,height) in your scrollview and no need of creating new view.

Comment: can you please edit in my code how to do this

Comment: Did you get a correct answer finally ?

Comment: @AliImran Did you get any solution for this ? I am also facing same problem. Getting full height of scrollview but it display only visible portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THis gives you the visible portion of the UIScrollView

```
CGRect visibleRect;
visibleRect.origin = scrollView.contentOffset;
visibleRect.size = scrollView.bounds.size;

float theScale = 1.0 / scale;
visibleRect.origin.x *= theScale;
visibleRect.origin.y *= theScale;
visibleRect.size.width *= theScale;
visibleRect.size.height *= theScale;
```

so you can use this in `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil);`
by some minor changes in the parameters.

Comment: where to write this code can you please edit in my code please

Comment: what is the scale can you please help me

Comment: `scale` is suppose to be the width of the UIScrollView

Comment: same problem it just show the visible area not the whole view

Comment: you want the whole data of ScrolVIew ryt..?

Comment: `CGFloat scrollViewHeight = 0.0f;
for (UIView* view in scrollView.subviews)
{
   scrollViewHeight += view.frame.size.height;
}`

ok this `scrollViewHeight` gives you the height of the scrollView contents portion so you need now is the width to get the bounds to replaCe `aView.bounds`

Comment: have you tried simply replacing  `aView.bounds` with `scrollView.bounds`  ??

Comment: giving two error at this line     UIView *view;
    view.frame = CGRectMake(scrollView.contentOffset, scrollView.contentOffset+scrollView.width, 320, scrollViewHeight );

Comment: yes it would... you need to put `(x origin of scrollView, y origin of scrollView, Width of scrollView, scrollViewHeight)`

Comment: you'll need to update these parameters according to your scrollView values.

Comment: you told to give content offset or x origin of scrollView i think we need to give content offset

Comment: check my update answer it is getting the height and width of the scroller but not showing content

Comment: @AliImran : nice.. just now you need to pass the `bounds` of `scrollSize` to get the content from it

Comment: can u try passing `scrollSize.bounds` instead of just `scrollSize`

Answer (score 1):

```
(void)createPDFfromUIView:(UIScrollView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
{
    // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    // Get Scrollview size
    CGRect scrollSize = CGRectMake(aView.origin.x,aView.origin.y,aView.contentSize.width,aView.contentSize.height);

    // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, scrollSize, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData

    [aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
    NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

    NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

    // instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
    [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);
}
```

Comment: aView.originalx we have to give the original postion of scrollview

Comment: These answers have tricky solutions refer it : 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/5405944/1223897

http://stackoverflow.com/a/14292471/1223897

Comment: I have checked these twos but i am not getting clear from these

Comment: check my update code it also shows scroller but it does not show any content it mean it is getting scrollView sizes but not getting content

Answer (score 1):

This code i used to make pdf from uiscrollview and it does help but it will not be as good as if we draw on pdf -- please have look -- **Pdf from UIScrollView**

```
- (void) createPDF
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *directroyPath = nil;
    directroyPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp"];
    NSString *filePath = [directroyPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.pdf"];
    // check for the "PDF" directory
    NSError *error;
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {

    } else {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:directroyPath
                                  withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                                   attributes:nil
                                                        error:&error];
    }

    CGContextRef pdfContext = [self createPDFContext:_scrollView2.bounds path:(CFStringRef)filePath];
    NSLog(@"PDF Context created");

    /*
     Here limit of i is no of pages in your uiscrollview or
     you can use hit and trial here because there is a
     length of page is going to be equal to 
     the visible size of uiscrollView in your application 
   */

    for (int i = 0 ; i< 2 ; i++)
    {

        // page 1
        CGContextBeginPage (pdfContext,nil);

        //turn PDF upsidedown
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

       //here 365 is equal to the height of myScrollView.frame.size.height

        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, (i+1) * 365);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGContextConcatCTM(pdfContext, transform);

        //Draw view into PDF
        [_scrollView2.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
        CGContextEndPage (pdfContext);
        [_scrollView2 setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, (i+1) * 365) animated:NO];

    }
    CGContextRelease (pdfContext);
}

- (CGContextRef) createPDFContext:(CGRect)inMediaBox path:(CFStringRef) path
{
    CGContextRef myOutContext = NULL;
    CFURLRef url;
    url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (NULL, path,
                                         kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle,
                                         false);

    if (url != NULL) {
        myOutContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL (url,
                                                  &inMediaBox,
                                                  NULL);
        CFRelease(url);
    }
    return myOutContext;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to convert the scrollview content into a PDF file is to have a content view as the first subview of the scrollview and using that view to take a snapshot of the scrollview. The code in Swift would look like this:

```
func generatePDFdata(withView view: UIView) -> NSData {

  let pageDimensions = view.bounds
  let outputData = NSMutableData()

  UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(outputData, pageDimensions, nil)
  if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
      UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
      view.layer.render(in: context)
  }
  UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

  return outputData
}
```

You can then use the `outputData` to write into a PDF file:

```
outputData.write(to: pdfFileUrl, atomically: true)
```