# How to convert text entered in the uitextview in to pdf

Tags: ios, pdf, uitextfield

when I add some text in the textview, onclick of convert to pdf,then i have to convert textview text to pdf file.

can anyone give some solution for this problem.

Thanks for quick response

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562085/create-pdf-from-uiscrollview-objective-c ?

Comment: @larme Thanks for reply the link which you have sent is not clear,so please give me  some other clear solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this code.

```
NSString *text = @"this is textField's text";
NSMutableData *pdfData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480), nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
[text drawInRect:UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds() withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17]}];
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
NSString *file = @"file.pdf"; //this is the file name.
NSArray<NSURL *> *dir = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
if (dir.count > 0){
    NSURL *path = [[dir firstObject] URLByAppendingPathComponent:file];
    [pdfData writeToFile:path.path atomically:false];
}
```

You can provide any formatting options you want in the withAttributes dictionary in the draw method.

And if you want multiple pages in your PDF just put this code in a loop

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
[text drawInRect:UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds() withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17]}];
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

and change the text that draws. You can draw images too if you want them in your PDF.
Check the created PDF
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer,I am using objective c, can you please give answer in objective c language

Comment: No  need this is default of obj c. import UIKit and foundation alone

Comment: It is not working and it is showing following error in the log pdfconvert[1499] <Error>: replacing +/-infinity with -2147483648.
Nov  2 17:29:16  pdfconvert[1499] <Error>: replacing +/-infinity with 2147483647.

Comment: It shows an error in the logs but when you open the file location you'll see your PDF